# How to convert scaling from SVG units to pixels using scale formula?

Tags: javascript, svg, formula, pixel, scaletransform

Previously, [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144367/how-to-get-current-values-from-attribute-d-of-svg-path-when-transform-property) how to obtain the real coordinates (`d`) of a `path` when a transformation is applied, finally I decided to investigate the transformation formulas, I have already seen the translation, and now I am seeing the scaling (scale), I managed to do a scaling Basically the formula is:

`x’ = x * sx`

`y’ = y * sy`

If I have a path where `d` attribute (command) of `M5, 5 L50, 5 L50, 45 L5, 45 Z`, and, If we inspect the path in the DOM, we'll find that it has a `width` of `135px` and a `height` of `120px`:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
  <path id="element" d="M5, 5 L50, 5 L50, 45 L5, 45 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" />
</svg>
```

So if I wanted to scale this path using a **scale factor** of `2`, it would be `M10, 10 L100, 10 L100, 90 L10, 90`, but if we now inspect the path in the DOM, the width is `270px` and its `height` is `240px`:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
<path id="element" d="M10, 10 L100, 10 L100, 90 L10, 90 Z" fill="none" stroke="white" />
</svg>
```

Therefore, the value or scale factor of `2` is equivalent to a `width` of `135px` and a `height` of `120px`, so:

How can I make this scale factor or value equal to `1px`?

Is there a conversion formula?

Playing around, I managed to guess that if the scale factor is:

`1.1 = 15px` -> therefore, the `width` would be `135px` increasing to `150px` and the `height` would be `120px` increasing to `135px`.

`1.01 = 1.5px` -> therefore, the `width` would be `135px` increasing to `136.5px` and the `height` would be `120px` increasing to `121.5px`.

I hope you have understood what I want to do, I hope you can help me.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/fontello/svgpath I personally use their parser for one of my project which works pretty well, but they also have many transform methods (that I didn't test personally). Note that it **should** have been simpler to parse the path data from a `<path>` element thanks to its [`getPathData()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-paths/#InterfaceSVGPathSegment) method, but browsers don't implement it...

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "scale based on pixels".  Can you elaborate please?  Your question is quite long, but you don't really explain clearly what it is exactly that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau I've re-edited the question, I tried to explain much better now, let me know if you don't understand something.

Comment: What is your end goal here exactly? You want to animate the scaling of this path? Why not use the `transform` attribute then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I get what you are saying, but your formulas don't seem to make sense.

> 1.1 = 15px -> therefore, the width would be 135px increasing to 150px
> and the height would be 120px increasing to 135px

That "15px" seems wrong.  `1.1 * 135 = 148.5`, not `150`.

What I think you are asking is how to calculate the scale that would make the width become 150. Is that right?

The scale that will get the width to exactly 150 can be calculated like this:

```
         new_width     150
scale = ----------- = ----- = 1.1111...
         old_width     135
```

So checking that: `135 * 1.1111... = 150.0`.

And the new height using this scale would be: 120 * 1.1111... = 133.333...